# "protocol handshake on connection" error logged in ActiveMQ Artemis console

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am using Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.30.0. Suddenly, I encountered a protocol handshake error causing the broker to become very slow. After a few minutes I am unable to open the web console even after entering the username and password. This is the problem I am facing today.

```
2023-10-05 11:11:44,640 INFO [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Logging in user: admin
2023-10-05 11:14:35,463 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to null has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-10-05 11:14:35,463 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to null has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-10-05 11:14:35,463 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to null has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-10-05 11:14:39,055 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to null has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-10-05 11:14:43,476 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to null has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-10-05 11:14:43,476 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to null has been detected: An existing Connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-10-05 11:14:43,492 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to null has been detected: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2023-10-05 11:14:43,508 ERROR[org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224126: Failure during protocol handshake on connection to /172.16.7.55:1883 from /172.16.8.100:62990 java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

```xml
<connectors>
   <connector name="amq1">tcp://ppr-t24-qve-01:61616</connector>
   <connector name="amq2">tcp://ppr-t24-qve-02:61616</connector>
</connectors>
<acceptors>
   <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
   <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP,CORE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
   <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP,CORE;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
   <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
   <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT,CORE;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
</acceptors>
```

Comment: because of this issue error "AMQ224126: Failure during protocol handshake on connection to /172.16.7.55:1883 from /172.16.8.100:62990" Artemis MQ came down, Any suggestion to resolve this issue please

Comment: I am using Apache ActiveMQ Artemis broker version 2.30. Suddenly, I encountered a protocol handshake error, causing the Artemis MQ broker to become very slow. After a few minutes, I am unable to open the MQ Web console even after entering the username and password. This is the problem I am facing today.

Comment: Hi Justin,
We have investigated the protocol issue mentioned above. This error did not cause any MQ slowness or MQ issues, but we are curious to resolve the issue because we are still experiencing it today. It is possible that it might be related to a firewall issue from the client to the MQ server ?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

The evidence you've provided indicates that you have an MQTT client connecting to port `1883` and this client is either misbehaving and forcibly closing the network connection unexpectedly or perhaps the network is failing between the client and the broker (e.g. potentially due to a firewall). In either case there's nothing the broker can do about it. It is simply reporting the error.

Comment: Today, suddenly received an error in Artemis, indicating that the master broker had gone down. We also received the same error. We checked the firewall and found no issues. In the event of a firewall issue, the broker should indeed go down, correct?

AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) on acceptor "artemis" during protocol handshake with /172.16.6.41:65097 has occurred.
AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.16.6.41:53480 has been detected: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /172.16.6.41:53480 within the 30000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed